# Android SQLite Delete not changing anything

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following method in my SQL class:

```
public void deleteEntry(int idnum) {
     dbSQL.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = 0", null);
}
```

I usually give it an `idnum` but for testing purposes I've just put a 0 there. Syntax wise, is there any reason why this wouldn't work? I've tried everthing.

Comment: Is there any data with KEY_ROWID = 0 ?

Comment: how did you check, nothing is changed.if your key_rowid is auto number than it starts from 1,not 0.

Comment: @KKD I'm trying to get it to delete the row where KEY_ROWID is 0. I know that exists and I'm testing. KEY_ROWID is a string for "_id" (the primary key column in the database)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `KEY_ROWID` is an autoincrementing primary key, the first record you enter will have value `1`, not `0`.

That being said, the reason why your `delete` method isn't working is most likely because there is no record with value `0`.

---

### Edit #1:

If I were you, I would uninstall and re-install your app and start from scratch. Either that, or use `adb` to analyze the contents of your SQLite database (using the emulator, if you don't have a rooted device). You can find the database file on the disk at `/data/data/[package name]/databases/database_name.db` (or something like that).

The best way to figure out why things aren't working at this point is to analyze the contents of the database. Otherwise you will just be guessing and checking until something appears to work... and even then you probably won't know for sure if your implementation is 100% correct.

---

### Edit #2:

As an alternative to analyzing the database file using the emulator and/or your rooted device, you could perform a query for **ALL** data in the database, and then use the [`dumpCursor`](http://tinyurl.com/7zwkqc3) method provided in the [`DatabaseUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) class to print the contents of the `Cursor` to `System.out`.

Comment: I tried a few of the methods with 1, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: If I were you, I would uninstall and re-install your app and start over. Either that, or use `adb` to analyze the contents of your SQLite database. You can find it located at `/data/data/[package name]/databases/database_name.db` (or something like that). If you don't have a rooted device, then use the emulator to debug it instead.

Comment: The best way to figure out why things arent working at this point is to analyze the contents of the database... otherwise you are just going to be guessing and checking until something appears to work... and even then you probably won't know for sure if it is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this version,

```
public void deleteEntry(int idnum) {
     dbSQL.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[] {"0"});
}
```

With `0` it will probably not work because if the column is `INTEGER` and `AUTOINCREMENT` it will start counting at a value greater then `0` so there isn't a row with the KEY_ROWID `0` to delete.

Comment: That also does not delete the row.

Comment: @MarkLyons Did you print the `KEY_ROWID` values from the database, do you have a row with `0` value for the `KEY_ROWID`?

Comment: I know that a row with KEY_ROWID of 0, so I'm using that to test. Realistically, the idnum parameter would be the one to delete, if that makes it easier.

Comment: @MarkLyons For `idnum` you would use my version like this : `new String[] {"" + idnum}`. Have you printed out the rows of your database to see what you actually have in there, in the database? The code from my answer is correct and it should delete a value if there is something to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to,

```
public void deleteEntry(int idnum) {
      dbSQL.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID+"=?", new Integer[]{idnum});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your KEY_ROWID column is string than you have to use

```
public void deleteEntry(int idnum) {
     dbSQL.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = '0'", null);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure...? I believe the `SQLiteDatabase` implementation will format your `WHERE` clause for you, so long as you pass the method a `String`.

Comment: I got an 'Invalid character constant' error for the body of that method.

Comment: Now you are treating `0` as a String, rather than an int? How is that any better?

Comment: @Rasel, no change :(. The KEY_ROWID column was set up in the table as: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, does that change anything?

Comment: @Alex Lockwood.See the authors comment.He is testing this by keeping the column String.thats why row with 0 was not deleted

Comment: SQLite is has data type affinity, so `_id = 0` (integer) is identical to `_id = '0'` (string)

Comment: @Sam, exactly... so it should make no difference.

Comment: @Rasel, I am 110% certain that your code should work as you have it written. I am not joking!! I have done it before and it should work perfectly fine the way you have it!

Comment: @MarkLyons,then your first row should start with 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, but I had some luck by just using a method I had built that took the id and returned the name associated with that entry and it successfully deletes corresponding items now.

Comment: Bear in mind that just because you found a workaround for the task at hand, it doesn't mean there still isn't something wrong with your code. It's better to be safe than sorry...